# PHP: Save the file returned by wget with file_put_content

Tags: php, wget, file-put-contents

I'm replacing a function that downloads a file with cURL and returns its content in a variable, then outside the function the code writes this variable to a file with file_put_content.
Because of requirements of the system I have to use wget now, so I'm using something like this:

```
function GetData($strdata,$wwwurl){
    $content = exec("wget --post-data '".$strdata."' -qO- ".$wwwurl);
    return $content;
}
```

But when I later use file_put_content to save the content of $content, the size of the file is way smaller than it should be (1kb when it should be around 480kb).
I can't remove file_put_content as it's used in several places of the code (that would take us a very long time) and all I can edit must be into that function.
If I launch wget with "-O test.zip" instead of "-O-" the file is downloaded and saved fine, the same happens if I launch the command from command line.
Any ideas?

Comment: Great, so you looked at the _size_ of the file … did you also look _inside_ of it, to check what it actually contains now (or make a debug output of `$content` in the above function)? That might be an error message or something.

Comment: The "good" file is a .zip containing some sql files, the "bad" one can't be unzipped, but if I open it with notepad I can see some lines of garbage and a couple of names from the sql files.

Comment: If you are in control of the target URL of the request, then I would continue investigating there - log the request headers & body, and see what the differences are between your working version of the wget call on the command line, and from within your PHP script.

Comment: (And even if you are not in control of it, you can set up your own script that does the logging of the request parameters, and target that one for testing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because `exec` doesn't return the whole data. Take a look at the documentation
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php :

> Return Values: The last line from the result of the command.

But `shell_exec` (or just backticks) returns whole data: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php .

Example:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/02/zip_5MB.zip';

$content = exec("wget -qO- $url");

var_dump(strlen($content));

$content2 = shell_exec("wget -qO- $url");

var_dump(strlen($content2));


file_put_contents('1.zip', $content);
file_put_contents('2.zip', $content2);
```

Output:

```
int(208)
int(5452018)
```

2.zip works (all 5MB data), 1.zip obviously not (just some bytes from the end).

So don't treat `exec`'s return value as the whole output of the command.